# Beyond Full-HD with Canon EOS 600D?

Tags: video

In video mode, my Canon EOS 600D can output up to a resolution of 1920 x 1080.
Of course, this resolution is a standard (full HD). But then again, even `exiftool` applied to an output *.MOV file tells me that the cropped image size is 2592 x 1728 (not to mention sensor size 5344 x 3516). While such video is ready to use as Full HD video out of the box, shouldn't this allow me to obtain significantly higher resolution video output (comparable to RAW for images, though still below the next bigger standard of 4K)?

Admittedly, *after* editing one would certainly crop and/or scale to Full HD anyway, but who would complain about a few extra pixels in footage *during* editing?
Or would using this resolution cause other (technical) problems (e.g., with writing speed)?

Comment: [Related](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76376/how-to-record-videos-at-full-resolution-with-nikon-d750-for-astrophotography).

Comment: "But then again, even exiftool applied to an output *.MOV file tells me that the cropped image size is 2592 x 1728 (not to mention sensor size 5344 x 3516)." - elaborate please.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow What I wanted to express is that hidden in the EXIT data are sizes that are much larger than 1920x1080 and might be relevant / exploitable

Comment: still says nothing to me. Copypaste the output part which makes you think so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the math, you will find that a full-res video would need to process too much data per time - 22Mpixel x 30 frames x 3x14 bit color depth = 3+ GByte/second (done in my head, double-check!)

The camera sensor is probably able to provide this data, but neither the in-camera chip nor the memory card is able to process such a data stream fast enough; and the buffers would be full after 2 or 3 seconds of video. Therefore, the camera makers chose to not offer this mode.

I guess if you hack the camera software, you could it make record on that resolution for one or two seconds.

Comment: Hm, so maybe with one of those adapters that look ike a SD card to the camera but actually connect to a PC? Also, `exiftool` reports for example 48.2 Mbps (or 6 MByte/second; also I do only 25 fps usually), but that's of course with some compressing codec and 2x8=24 bit color depth and 4:2:2 etc.. So if we drop the RAW demand, I suppose the merely expanded *size* of the frame might not yet make an obstacle?